# mongoDb $set and $setOnInsert on field in sub properties

Tags: typescript, mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have a document with a sub property

```
{
  a: string,
  b: {
    aplus: string,
    c: string,
    d: string,
  }
}
```

I only want to set the aplus field on an insert operation during upserts

This is close to what I am trying to do:

```
  const { subproperties, ...rest } = newRecord;
  const updateProperties = subproperties;
  delete updateProperties?.aplus;
  await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      id: newRecord.id,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        ...rest,
        subproperties: updateProperties,
      },
      $setOnInsert: {
        "subproperties.aplus": newRecord.aplus,
      },
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
    }
  );
```

I keep getting this error: Cannot update subproperties and subproperties at the same time. I am deleting the aplus field from the update data, however it seems that because I reference the aplus field through subproperties field it gets confused.

How can I rewrite this so that mongo knows I only wish to affect the aplus field inside the subproperties not the whole subproperties field in the $setOnInsert, i.e. I still want the c and d field to be updated? Is there a way to know I am doing an insert in the $set so I could do the conditional there?

EDIT: should be mentioned I am using documentDb in aws, which I believe is based on mongo 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally stumbled onto the solution here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5285
which suggests using the dotify function

```
export function dotify(obj: object) {
  const res: any = {};

  function recurse(obj: any, current?: string) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      const value = obj[key];
      const newKey = current ? current + "." + key : key;
      if (value && typeof value === "object" && !Array.isArray(value)) {
        recurse(value, newKey);
      } else {
        res[newKey] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  recurse(obj);
  return res;
}

  const { subproperties, ...rest } = newRecord;
  const updateProperties = subproperties;
  delete updateProperties?.aplus;
  await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      id: newRecord.id,
    },
    {
      $set: dotify({
        ...rest,
        subproperties: updateProperties,
      }),
      $setOnInsert: {
        "subproperties.aplus": newRecord.a,
      },
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
    }
  );
```

Regular fields including objects seem to work this way when dotified, however mongoose (or the version of documentDb that is running in aws) does not handle dotified arrays, they turn out undefined (maybe schema related?), so I only do it for actual objects. Documentdb is using a fairly back leveled mongoDb, so it possible this has been fixed in later versions.